# Back button and backspace not working in IE on a page with a fixed top div and named links

Tags: javascript, css

Either the Back button nor backspace is working in IE on a page with a fixed top div and named links.

**Edit**: I've clarified my problem with this updated code. Everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .divButtons
        {
            z-index: 999;
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height: 38px;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            background-color: #f3f3f3;
            border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid;              
        }
        .divFullViewArea
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 38px;
        }
        .divViewArea
        {
            padding-top: 20px;
        }
    </style>

    <!--[if IE]>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0px
        }
        html {
            min-height: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto
        }
        body {
            min-height: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto
        }
        .divFullViewArea {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 8px; width: 100%; padding-right: 8px; height: 95%; overflow: auto; padding-top: 8px
        }
        .divFullViewArea * {
            margin: auto
        }
        .divButtons {
            position: fixed; margin: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px
        }
        * html .divButtons {
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>      
    <div class="divButtons">
        Top
    </div>
    <div class="divFullViewArea">
        <p>
            <a id="link1" href="#chapter1">Chapter 1</a>
            <br>
            <a id="link2" href="#chapter2">Chapter 2</a>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <a name="chapter1">Chapter 1</a>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <a name="chapter2">Chapter 2</a>
            <br>
            <br>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem to be possible to combine my current CSS with anchor links. My solution is to use this CSS instead: [Making IE 5.5+ use position: fixed;](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/fixedPosition.html)

Answer (score 0):

Removing `overflow:auto;` would fix your issue.

Like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div style="position:relative; height: 150px; width: 200px; ">  
        <p>
            <a id="link1" href="#chapter1">Chapter 1</a>
            <br>
            <a id="link2" href="#chapter2">Chapter 2</a>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <a id="chapter1">Chapter 1</a>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <a id="chapter2">Chapter 2</a>
            <br>
            <br>
        </p>        
    </div>
</body>
```

Do you need it to be there? IMO it creates an additional scrolling on the div that should be avoided.

Comment: I updated the code example. My initial code snippet was in fact a part of a web page with a fixed top div. Would you please look at my updated code? Thanks.

Comment: It's the overflow:auto that still creates you trouble. This time in CSS:

remove it from `.divFullViewArea` class
......
Ah, I see now... you want the Top bar to stay in place.

Comment: Yes, I want the top bar to stay in place. So what should I do?

Comment: That would be a bit harder, given your current construction. Can you tell me what is it that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I was trying to have a fixed bar at the top. However it does not seem to be possible to combine my current CSS with anchor links. My solution is to use this CSS instead: [link](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/fixedPosition.html).